# How to load events from Database to display on adesigns/calendar-bundle?

Tags: fullcalendar, symfony

I am using adesigns/calendar-bundle. The calendar is already showing. However, when I click on any given date, it does not let me add an event. Moreover, I have create an entity class that is persisted to the database to store events. I load them and when I want to display them, it throws me an error: http://localhost/guilford/web/app_dev.php/fc-load-events Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

CalendarListener.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Event\CalendarEvent;
use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Entity\EventEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CalendarEventListener
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendarEvent)
    {

        $request = $calendarEvent->getRequest();
        $filter = $request->get('filter');



        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $events =$em->getRepository('AppBundle:CalendarEvent')
                    ->findAll();

        foreach ($events as $event) {

             // create an event with a start/end time, or an all day event
            if ($event->getAllDay() === false) {
                $eventEntity = new EventEntity($event->getTitle(), $event->getStartDate(), $event->getEndDate());
            } else {
                $eventEntity = new EventEntity($event->getTitle(), $event->getStartDate(), null, true);
            }         

            $calendarEvent->addEvent($eventEntity);
        }

    }
}
```

Calendar-settings.js

```
$(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    $('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev, next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay,'
        },
        lazyFetching: true,
        timeFormat: {
            // for agendaWeek and agendaDay
            agenda: 'h:mmt',    // 5:00 - 6:30

            // for all other views
            '': 'h:mmt'         // 7p
        },

        eventSources: [
            {

                url: Routing.generate('fullcalendar_loader'),
                type: 'POST',
                // A way to add custom filters to your event listeners
                data: {
                },
                error: function() {
                   alert('There was an error while fetching Google Calendar!');
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: services.yml




    services:
    appbundle.calendar_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: calendar.load_events, method: loadEvents }
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']

Comment: 500 error should give you a php error log, check that for more info on whats happening.